# How build formula IF in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have  data in excel:

```
N:    1     2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

H:    9.5   9.4 6.5 V   9.5 KR  9.0 8.5 5     7

If H >=7 then NC= 1 esle NC=0.5
If H=V or H=KR then NC=0
```

I want caculator total of NC from 1 to 10
How build formula in Excel?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at what I think you're looking for.  Given a data setup like this:

[image: Total of NC]

In cell D2 is this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B11,">=7")+COUNTIF(B2:B11,"<7")*0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you can just nest `IF`s, putting another `IF` inside the true or false clause.

Arbitrarily assuming your value of `H` is in cell A2:

```
=IF(OR(A2 = "V", A2 = "KR"), 0, IF(A2 >= 7, 1, 0.5))
```

Comment: caculator: total of NC from 1 to 10

Comment: So put a sum at the end?

Comment: i want a formula caculator of NC for:

H:    9.5   9.4 6.5 V   9.5 KR  9.0 8.5 5     7

Comment: @user1497597 You are not making any sense at all. Could you put the results you expect in your question?